# strace calls from running process and count them

Tags: ubuntu, background-process, system-calls, strace

I have a background process that will run for many many hours. I would like to trace and count the number of `write` calls live.

```
sudo strace -p27861 -s50 -e write
```

It gives me lines like this:

```
write(1, "...........", 70) = 70
```

What I would like to have is to get a live count of this calls like that:

```
write(1, "...........", 70) = 70, 1
write(1, "...........", 560) = 560, 2
write(1, "...........", 103) = 103, 3
```

or only counts:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Did you try `awk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by post-processing the output, for example using GNU AWK:

```
strace -q -p27861 -s50 -e write -e signal=none 2>&1 | gawk '{ print $0 ", " ++i }'
```

(which gives exactly the output you’re after, live), or `cat -n` as suggested by [user414777](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/414777/user414777):

```
strace -q -p27861 -s50 -e write -e signal=none 2>&1 | cat -n
```

`-q` suppresses the “Attaching” message, and `-e signal=none` suppresses the signal traces.